# Android Export Data in CSV

Tags: android, android-intent

Hi Folks I am developing a app and need an option to export the app data in CSV format. I am using the following code for the same

```
FileOutputStream out = openFileOutput("test_data.csv", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
out.write(data.toString().getBytes());
out.close();

//Exporting file
Context context = getApplicationContext();
File filelocation = new File( getFilesDir(),"test_data.csv");

Uri path = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context,"com.j4ss.bpmonitor.FileProvider", filelocation);
Intent fileIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
fileIntent.setType("text/csv");
fileIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Test Data");
fileIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
fileIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,path);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(fileIntent, "Send Data"));
```

`
Now when i execute and press the export option, the emulator gives me two options Google Drive and Gmail. Google Drive works fine and i am able to export the data as CSV to google drive. The problem is with GMAIL. when i click on the Gmail option, it opens Gmail with the correct and even shows the CSV file as an attachment. However when i send the mail, the mail goes successfully, but the attachment does not go.

I have read that this is beacuse GMAIL cannot read a file from internal storage. To test this I tried creating the file in the External Storage of the emulator and GMAIL attachment worked fine. I need an option to be able to use the GMAIL attachment feature even if the mobile does not have external storage. Any ideas how to achieve this? Thanks.